# How to load a large number of images in Pygame by a simple way?

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7, converters

I'm currently working on a game on Pygame. Recently, someone helped me to make my loading bar on this website (*god, Rabbid76 is a genius*). More seriously, I need to load all the pictures in my program so I've used the following code :
! (I've used *'picture'* as a placeholder, in my real directory, it's '*hero_left0.png*' or '*box.png*' or '*Torch.png*', and so on):

```
Image=picture.image.load(sprite/picture.png).convert_alpha
bar_load=bar_load - 1
```

And I need to do this to fit any picture. Which means 350*2 elements, so 700 lines of code!

Is there a way to optimize this? All pictures are in the same folder name *'sprites'*.

Comment: Thank for the editing suggestion, I need to improve my english, and my keyboard is in a other language xD

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you please revise your question so it follows the guidelines in [ask]? For example, try construct a [mcve]. The code you've provided is a bit confusing. What is `picture.image.load`? And did you mean to write `.convert_alpha()` instead of `.concert_alpha`? And what is `bar_load`? Also, what are you trying to accomplish? Loading 700 pictures do seem to be the wrong approach, as you'll probably run out of memory. Try also to minimize spelling errors, such as _Pyrame,_ which users could misinterpret as another library than _Pygame._

Comment: Also, a couple of more questions. What are _"LIGNS"_? And what do you mean by optimize? In your title you write that you want it done in a simple way, but I interpret optimize as doing something fast or with as little memory as possible.

Comment: Sorry my autocorrector, I hate this feature on Android keyboard

Comment: I dont remember exactly how it works, but there is an OS function called walk() that will return a list of all files under a given directory. you can look into that.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman When he says optimise he means a for loop or something that doesnt involve 700 lines of redundant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it you want to get all of your images loaded into your code. You should store all your image objects in a dict or some other structure.
Do it something like this:

```
import os

# If using windows make sure to convert all the '\' in the path to '/'
# like so: sprites_folder_path.replace('\', '/')
sprites_folder_path = 'path_to_sprites_folder'
# Make sure there is a '/' at the end of the path 

def image_loader(path) -> str:
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        yield (os.path.splitext(i)[0]),
               picture.image.load(path + i).concert_alpha)


images = dict(image_loader(sprite_folder_ path))
```

This generates a dict of all the image objects as the values and the filenames as the keys. You can refer to each image: `images[filename].`

Or if you wanted to be really concise about it then;

```
def image_loader(path) -> str:
    return dict((os.path.splitext(i)[0]), picture.image.load(path + i).concert_alpha) for i in os.listdir(path))
```

*NOTE: This will work only is all your filenames are valid python variable names, if not use something else as the keys of the dict or rename the ones that are not valid*

Comment: I don't understand at all your code, can you explain me this last ?

Comment: @Edhyjox the basic structure is that the paths list contains all the paths of the filenames of the images in your sprite folder, keys list is generated by getting the filename of the image of each image in the paths list, then taking out the file extn. (eg. .png, .jpg) with the splitext function. Then the dict is created by the zip() function. I suggest you read the documentation to understand how that works, i won't do it justice by explaining it in a comment.

Comment: All picture extensions are .'png', so maybe a way to improve it again ?

Comment: @Edhyjox there won't be any significant performance increase as the plaintext function is pretty fast anyways, and the improvement will do the same thing as the splitest function in any case, also it makes the code more robust, just in case a picture of a different file format is used for whatever reason

Comment: Did Pyrame read svg format un this case ? That thé only way I think to use a other extension.

Comment: @Edhyjox I have no idea. Try it out :)

Comment: Ok, let's restart thé computer xD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187840/discussion-between-param-kapur-and-edhyjox).

Answer (score 0):

Refactored version of [Param Kapur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54503270/how-to-load-a-large-number-of-images-in-pygame-by-a-simple-way/54503792#54503792) (which wasn't proper pygame code as of adding this answer):

```py
    import os
    import pygame


    sprites_folder_path = "path_to_sprites_folder"
    
    
    def image_loader(path: str) -> str:
        for i in os.listdir(path):
            yield ((os.path.splitext(i)[0]),
                   pygame.image.load(path + i).convert_alpha())

    sprites = dict(image_loader(sprites_folder_path))
```